# How do I nest a variable that is a string inside of another variable that is a saved output of a command?

Tags: bash, variable, curl, jq

How do I nest a variable that is a string inside of another variable that is a saved output of a command?

I want to accomplish what this code does:

```
xmrprice=$(curl -s 'https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=bitcoin%2Cbitcoin-cash%2Clitecoin%2Cmonero&vs_currencies=usd&include_market_cap=true' |jq -r '.monero'|jq -r '.usd')
echo "The price of Monero is $xmrprice"
btcprice=$(curl -s 'https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=bitcoin%2Cbitcoin-cash%2Clitecoin%2Cmonero&vs_currencies=usd&include_market_cap=true' |jq -r '.bitcoin'|jq -r '.usd')
echo "The price of BTC is $btcprice"
ltcprice=$(curl -s 'https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=bitcoin%2Cbitcoin-cash%2Clitecoin%2Cmonero&vs_currencies=usd&include_market_cap=true' |jq -r '.litecoin'|jq -r '.usd')
echo "The price of Litecoin is $ltcprice"
```

but without calling `curl` three times. Removing the `-s` flag would demonstrate that curl is indeed called three times. I want to assign the string from the output of

```
curl -s https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=bitcoin%2Cbitcoin-cash%2Clitecoin%2Cmonero&vs_currencies=usd&include_market_cap=true
```

to a variable and then extract from it the values of `xmrprice`, `brcprice`, and `ltcprice`.
Much like this Python code does it:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

#pip3 install requests

import requests
import json

result = requests.get("https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=bitcoin%2Cbitcoin-cash%2Clitecoin%2Cmonero&vs_currencies=usd&include_market_cap=true", headers = {"accept":"application/json"})

print("Monero's and Bitcoin's prices as of now:")
print(str(result.json()["monero"]["usd"]))
print(str(result.json()["bitcoin"]["usd"]))
```

I have [come across this question on nesting variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651437/how-do-i-set-a-variable-to-the-output-of-a-command-in-bash) in Bash but it relates more to assigning a nested outputs of multiple commands to a variable.

I've tried all this:

```
response=$(curl -s https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=bitcoin%2Cbitcoin-cash%2Clitecoin%2Cmonero&vs_currencies=usd&include_market_cap=true)
#xmrprice=(${response}|jq -r '.monero'|jq -r '.usd') #syntax error near unexpected token `|'
#xmrprice=("${response}"|jq -r '.monero'|jq -r '.usd') #syntax error near unexpected token `|'
#xmrprice=$("${response}"|jq -r '.monero'|jq -r '.usd') #{"error":"Missing parameter vs_currencies"}: command not found
#xmrprice=$("{response}"|jq -r '.monero'|jq -r '.usd') #: {response}: command not found

echo "The price of Monero is ${xmrprice}".
```

None of it works. The comments describe the errors that I got
from Bash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close to what you're looking for. You're only missing an `echo`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
response=$(curl -s 'https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=bitcoin%2Cbitcoin-cash%2Clitecoin%2Cmonero&vs_currencies=usd&include_market_cap=true')
xmrprice=$(echo "${response}"|jq -r '.monero'|jq -r '.usd')
echo "${xmrprice}"
```

Edit: As pointed out by Kusalananda, you are also missing the quotes around the URL in your curl command.

Comment: You need to quote the URL or you break that line apart into a `curl` call and two variable assignments. Why do you call `jq` twice?  `jq -r '.monero.usd'` would work too...  Also note that `echo` may modify the string that it is outputting by interpreting some backslash character sequences.

Comment: I only wanted to help around the `bash` issues, not the `jq` ones.

Comment: You shouldn't use `echo` for arbitrary data, especially those that are likely to contain backslash characters such as json data. See [Why is printf better than echo?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803)

Comment: @Stéphane `printf "%s\n" "$xmrprice"` instead of using `echo` would do?

Comment: @JerzyBrzóska, yes, though it's probably even more important to do it for `$response` which is the one likely to contain backslashes. `printf '%s\n' "$response" | ...`. In the case of `jq`, the trailing newline is not necessary, so `printf %s "$response" | jq...` would be enough.

Answer (score 3):

I would probably do this:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

unset -v xmrprice btcprice ltcprice

url='https://api.coingecko.com/endpoint/path'

eval "$(
    curl -s "$url" |
    jq -r '
        @sh "xmrprice=\(.monero.usd|tonumber)",
        @sh "btcprice=\(.bitcoin.usd|tonumber)",
        @sh "ltcprice=\(.litecoin.usd|tonumber)"'
)"

printf '%s is %s\n' \
    'xmrprice' "$xmrprice" \
    'btcprice' "$btcprice" \
    'ltcprice' "$ltcprice"
```

This calls `curl` *once* and passes the resulting document through a *single* `jq` invocation without having to store it in a file or variable.  The `jq` expression creates three strings.  Each string is a variable assignment.  The `@sh` operator in `jq` makes sure that the string is properly quoted for the shell.

The `eval` evaluates the variable assignments, creating the three shell variables.

Note that none of the quotes used in the code, whether single or double, are accidental or unneeded (apart from the single quotes around the plain strings in the arguments to `printf` at the end, they are just for looking good).

---

If you're not actually interested in creating shell variables, then there is no need to do so as `jq` may be used to do the formatted output:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

url='https://api.coingecko.com/endpoint/path'

curl -s "$url" |
jq -r '
    "xmrprice is at \(.monero.usd|tonumber) USD",
    "btcprice is at \(.bitcoin.usd|tonumber) USD",
    "ltcprice is at \(.litecoin.usd|tonumber) USD"'
```